# How to create simple continues slow moving css image slider?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Hi guys i am working on solution

i want to create image slider in which images are moving slowly to their respective left continuesly

I have tried to build it using marquee there is wide gap between two images once slider finished

Here is code

HTML:

```
<div class="marquee-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="marquee-block">
            <div class="marquee-inner to-left">
                <span>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">5</p>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="marquee-item">
                        <p class="text-white">5</p>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee-wrapper {
        background: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .marquee-wrapper .container {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .marquee-inner span {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .marquee-wrapper .marquee-block {
        --total-marquee-items: 5;
        height: 64px;
        width: calc(64px * (var(--total-marquee-items)));
        overflow: hidden;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        background: #1B2531;
        padding: 0 0;
    }
    .marquee-inner {
        display: block;
        width: 200%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .marquee-inner p {
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: cursive;
    }
    .marquee-inner.to-left {
        animation: marqueeLeft 25s linear infinite;
    }
    .marquee-inner.to-right {
        animation: marqueeRight 25s linear infinite;
    }
    .marquee-item {
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
        float: left;
        transition: all .5s ease-out;
        background: #00cc00;
    }

    @keyframes marqueeLeft {
        0% {
            left: 0;
        }

        100% {
            left: -100%;
        }
    }

    @keyframes marqueeRight {
        0% {
            left: -100%;
        }

        100% {
            left: 0;
        }
    }
```

I would like to build something like below picture, here images are moving continutionly to left also i do not want to use any js liberary is it possible only using css?

Please help

[image]

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/janakprajapati90/Lke9wo63/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/

Comment: Nope my solution is different it does not fit with this one i already tried

Comment: Did you check the answer for the stackoverflow question? If you did and it's not applicable please [edit] the question and explain why you can't use existing solutions